# Unable to build android apk after adding googleplus plugin? ionic1

Tags: ionic-framework

```
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
C:\xampp\htdocs\encircle\ui\platforms\android\src\nl\xservices\plugins\GooglePlu
s.java:309: error: cannot find symbol
                result.put("familyName", acct.getFamilyName());
                                             ^
  symbol:   method getFamilyName()
  location: variable acct of type GoogleSignInAccount
C:\xampp\htdocs\encircle\ui\platforms\android\src\nl\xservices\plugins\GooglePlu
s.java:310: error: cannot find symbol
                result.put("givenName", acct.getGivenName());
                                            ^
  symbol:   method getGivenName()
  location: variable acct of type GoogleSignInAccount
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Getting above error while building the android apk. please help me to solve this.

Comment: Try to remove the plugin and platforms and readd it. If it's still not working try a release of the plugin like 5.0.0

Comment: I need plugin usage. I have to resolve error but not plugin removal. And one more thing is, it automatically adding the plugin while running `cordova build android`. I removed the plugin and platform but still getting the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried another version of the plugin ? If the plugin automatically added try to remove plugins and platforms folder maybe you have a wrong version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your Android SDK, especially the Play Services repository.

Comment: where I can Play Services repository? on SDK manager. Can you please provide me a screenshot? I am using android studio

Comment: You can find it on sdk manager:

http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-BLnYYNpmDf0/UMr8DI4mQpI/AAAAAAAAGgE/mM8bYAGPBMA/s1600/Google+Play+services+SDK_02.png (find this screenshot on google, i dont have android studio installed on my PC at the moment but that works for me).

Comment: I resolved that after updating SDK. Anyway thanks for your time